# Having problems with eclipse PDT after eclipse update

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

After upgrading my linux installation eclipse was updated from version "neon" to "oxygen". 
Now I have some strange problems:

- new FIXME comments were not recognized anymore as tasks in PHP
- syntax errors in PHP are still marked as error after fixing them, I have to delete the whole line and restore the line to go the error away
- spell checking is not working anymore, even it is enabled in preferences

Do I have to clean / update / convert something in the workspace, or where are this problems coming from?
In older versions of eclipse the DLTK database had to be deleted in the workspace metadata folder, this fixed similar issues some years ago.

Comment: Could you try it with a new workspace: switch to a new workspace and "Import… > General > Existing Projects into Workspace" with "Copy projects into workspace"?

Comment: I did. No change: error markers are still persistant. Also, Eclipse randomly stops responding until forcibly killed by Process Manager and restarted - this happens around 2-3 times every day. I'm currently evaluating whether bring back this project to Eclipse Mars or force it forward to JetBrains PHPStorm.